# Adding up a current variable with the previous one

Tags: javascript

I have a problem here, basically I want my Dice game to display 3 lines.
The first line says what number of the die I got
The second line adds the number I got from the first die with the second die i rolled and so on.. (basically everytime i click the button).
The third line would just count how many times I rolled the dice.

My problem is that on my second line, im not sure how I can add up my current die roll with my previous one everytime I click the button.

```
var count=0;
function swap_pic()
{
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
var pic = document.getElementById("dice");
var xx = x+x;
count++;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You got " + x;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<br>Your score is: " + xx;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<br>Number of tries = " + count;
    if (count==5)
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<br><span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;'>Game Over!</span>";
    count = 0;
    document.getElementById('button').setAttribute("style","visibility:hidden");
    }
    if (x==1)
    {
    pic.src = "images/die1.png";
    }
    else if (x==2)
    {
    pic.src = "images/die2.png";
    }
    else if (x==3)
    {
    pic.src = "images/die3.png";
    }
    else if (x==4)
    {
    pic.src = "images/die4.png";
    }
    else if (x==5)
    {
    pic.src = "images/die5.png";
    }
    else if (x==6)
    {
    pic.src = "images/die6.png";
    }
}
```

Problem is this line

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<br>Your score is: " + xx;
```

Thank you for the help guys!

Comment: Count the score outside of the function, just as you do with `count`? Also, `pic.src = "images/die"+ x +".png"`?

Comment: if u see the guy below what he posted, he tried it and still didnt work, the function didnt do anything, rather than displaying the results

Comment: I had just left an extra `var`, now it is fixed with my last edit (yesterday)

Answer (score 1):

Several concatenation of innerHTML should be avoided, as well as repeated `else if` when possible. Try this:

```
var count = 0;
var sum = 0;

function swap_pic() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var pic = document.getElementById("dice");
    sum += x;
    count++;
    var html = "You got " + x;
    html += "<br>Your score is: " + sum;
    html += "<br>Number of tries = " + count;
    if (count == 5) {
        html += "<br><span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;'>Game Over!</span>";
        count = 0;
        document.getElementById('button').setAttribute("style", "visibility:hidden");
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html;
    pic.src = "images/die" + x +".png";
}
```

Comment: The problem is with ur alteration, the game wont work, if I click the button nothing happens

Comment: The button? which button? I have not change much of your code, change made it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size

```
//create these as global variables
var totalScore;
var rollCount;
var lastRoll;
var image;
var text;
var button;

function reload(){
    totalScore  = 0;
    rollCount   = 0;
    lastRoll    = 0;
    image       = document.getElementById('dice'); //store image element
    text        = document.getElementById('result'); //store result element
    button      = document.getElementById('button'); //store button element
    button.style.visibility = visible; //restore button visibility
}

function roll(){
    lastRoll = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1; //generate random number
    rollCount++; //increase our roll counter
    totalScore+= lastRoll; //add new roll to score
    image.src = "images/die" +lastRoll+ ".png"; //update dice image

    text.innerHTML  = "You got " // generate result string
                    + lastRoll
                    + "<br>Your score is: " 
                    + totalScore
                    + "<br>Number of tries = " 
                    + rollCount;

    if(rollCount >= 5){ //end game parameter!!
        text.innerHTML  += "<br><span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;'>Game Over!</span>"; //add game over text
        button.style.visibility = 'hidden';//hide button
        //reload();  //uncomment to reset game now?
    }
}

window.onload = reload; //set up on page load
```